# TV Remote using a Cellphone

Tags: android, television

I was wondering if it's possible to build an app which works as a TV remote, I've been googling around but so far all I've found are apps that already do or attempt to do it, but nothing that gives me an idea of how to achieve this. Does anyone know? I want to try and do it for an android phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Phones generally don't have IR(infrared) ports, so that isn't much of an option.

Comment: that I know, but due to the lack of IR I can't control my tv :(?

Comment: You would have to maybe have a bluetooth device that handled the IR for you.  That could be an option.

Answer (score 0):

you can cling library 
its url is mentioned below 
http://4thline.org/projects/cling/